# Problem with predefined arguments on hackerearth platform

Tags: c++

I have a problem states:

> WRITE A PROGRAM TO FIND THE MINIMUM NUMBER IN A LIST OF GIVEN N INTEGERS.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int FindIt (vector<int> arr)
 {
    **//WRITE YOUR CODE HERE`enter code here`**

 }
 int main()
 {
     ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
     cin.tie(0);
     int n;
     cin>>n;
     vector<int> arr(n);
     for(int i_arr=0;i_arr < n;i_arr++)
     {
         cin>>arr[i_arr];
     }
     int out_;
     out_ =FindIt(arr);
     cout<<out_;
 }
```

I tried running the program with the below approach but every time it shows 0 as output.

I don't know any other approach as i am a beginner.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int FindIt (vector<int> arr)
 {
     int min=0;
     int n=arr.size();
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     {
         if(arr[i+1]<arr[i])
         min=arr[i+1];
     }
     return min;

 }
 int main()
 {
     ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
     cin.tie(0);
     int n;
     cin>>n;
     vector<int> arr(n);
     for(int i_arr=0;i_arr < n;i_arr++)
     {
         cin>>arr[i_arr];
     }
     int out_;
     out_ =FindIt(arr);
     cout<<out_;
 }
```

Comment: Think a bit harder about your indexing. What happens when `i == n-1`?

Comment: Are you sure `arr[i+1]<arr[i]` is the right condition? This will find the lower of two consecutive values, consider what will happen with an input of `1 3 2`.
see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Hi! Use a debugger or some cout statements to get a better understanding what your program is actually doing. Then the solution will become obvious! Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

The innocuously looking statement

```
 int min=0;
```

had introduced 0 as a value in your input. If all values in your input are increasing compared to preceding ones, the 0 is can be a "minimum" as the condition was never met. You have to compare vector element with current minimum, something like:

```
int min = arr[0];
for ( auto i = 1, n = arr.size(); i < n; i++)
   if(arr[i] < min)  
      min = arr[i];
```